# Tengo un problema con mi codigo :(

Tags: discord.js

Lo que ocurre es lo siguiente, para ejecutar un comando ocurre de la siguiente manera B!accion <acción>, lo que quiero es que se ejecute de la siguiente manera B!<acción> es deci, que solo sea el prefix, llevo horas intentando arreglarlo pero no puedo

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const accionReply = require('../mensajes/accion-reply');

module.exports = {
  name: "accion",
  description: 'Ejecuta una acción.',
  execute(message, args) {
    const accion = args.join('').toLowerCase();
    const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first(); 


    const comando = args[0]?.toLowerCase();


    if (!comando || !accionReply[comando]) {
      return message.reply('¡Esa acción no existe! :p');
    }


    const mensaje = accionReply[accion](message.author, targetUser);
    const gifURL = accionReply.getRandomGifURL(accion);

    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('RANDOM')
      .setDescription(mensaje)
      .setImage(gifURL);

    message.reply({ embeds: [embed] });
  },
};
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento dle sitio. Dale un título descriptivo a tu pregunta: uno el cual describa brevemente qué problema específicamente estás teniendo.